# Select em atributo String usando Split e LINQ?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

Eu tenho a seguinte string `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"` que quero fazer um `Split` em um `Select` para buscar no banco de dados se o número 9 esta inserido em um campo que recebe strings de números. Quero fazer isso usando o LINQ do C# sem ter que usar foreach ou algo semelhante.

Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim

```
public class SequenciaNumero {
     public string Numeros {get;set;}
}

SequenciaNumero sn = new SequenciaNumero();
sn.Numeros = "1,2,3,4,";

SequenciaNumero sn1 = new SequenciaNumero();
sn1.Numeros = "5,6,7,8,9,10,"

context.SequenciasNumeros.Add(sn, sn1);
context.SaveChanges();

//pesquisar numeros a partir de uma string de numeros
string _pesquisaNumeros = "10,11,12,15,"

//teste de split no LINQ
context.SequenciasNumeros
       .Select(x => x.Numeros.Split(new string[]{","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
       .Where(x => _pesquisaNumeros.Split(new string[]{","},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
       .Any(y => y.Equals(x)));

//erro
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.dll
```

No meu teste, estou tentando pesquisar a partir de uma string de numeros buscando os numeros que existem em comum no banco em strings. No caso, retornaria apenas o numero 10 que deveria ser encontrado q esta em `_pesquisaNumeros`

Comment: qual versão do Entity Framework? e também qual banco de dados?

Comment: @novic EF 6.4 e Mysql

Comment: então não vai funcionar porque ele não consegue traduzir isso para SQL, o que você pode fazer é na memória, mas, ai tem o custo do desempenho... não sei se vale a pena

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido.

```
var _myNum = context.SequenciasNumeros
                                    .AsEnumerable()
                                    .SelectMany(x => x.Numeros.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                                    .Intersect(_pesquisaNumeros.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                                    .ToArray();
```